# Android Studio - Logcat not working for emulator but OK for phone

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm very new to Android Studio. I have been using it on Windows but the machine was too old to run any of the emulators so I installed it (via Ubuntu Software store) on a laptop running Unbuntu 18.04.

It all seems to work OK except the Logcat does not show anything. Sometimes, after cold starting the emulator, I get some output to the Logcat but then it just halts and nothing I do (see below) causes it to output anything else.

**I cannot get ANY output when running an app.**

I have searched extensively here and via Google and tried the following:

1. restarted the Studio
2. restarted logcat
3. killed and restarted adb
4. invalidate caches and restart AS
5. deleting and recreating AVDs
6. use logcat via AS built in terminal and external shell :

   `./adb -s emulator-5554 logcat`

   and get:

   `Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory`

**NB: When using an attached phone e.g. Moto G. the logcat works fine. I get all the system output and the app output works as expected.**

Thanks in advance

**2019-12-14 UPDATE:** when the emulator is running it shows the active processes (see screenshot) in the drop down, including my app but NO entries. Not sure if this gives anyone a clue? It is clearly communicating with the emulator in some way.
[image]

**2019-12-16 UPDATE:**  Started in from scratch. Installed MX Linux 19 and fresh Studio install. Created new AVD. **EXACTLY THE SAME!!!** This is so ridiculous. Anyone, please?

Comment: Why it is reported for being Closed? Above seems a good question to me.

Comment: Have you tried "tapping on opened activity in your app"? Because it should print something on the log for it.

Comment: Try a different emulator image

Comment: Thanks Chris but, yes, I've tried 4 now, I think. All the same. I've even reinstalled AS from the Developer website and deleted the sdk inc. previous system images.

Comment: Malwinder, was my post closed then? I didn't see that. And nothing I do in any apps makes any entry to the log. There are no entries at all. However,  logging on a physically connected phone, with the same apps, work fine. It's a very strange issue!! :-(

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you might be trying to use a gun to kill a fly. For a try, ensure that the emulator you have run is actually selected in logcat like in this screen shot

. [image]